# Protecting WPF application with self-made key algorithm

Tags: c#, wpf, key

I need to find a way to lock a software product, so only customers who bought it can use it. I was thinking about implementing my own "CD-key" feature.

---

How it works:
I have a seperate program, that is used only for generating keys.

The program uses the same algorithm than the software being selled. The key is shipped with the program (on lets say the manuals) and entered in the program one time. After that the user can use it freely without ever entering it again(until reinstalling).

This looks pretty simple and doable to me, but the only problem is that the key can be reused on other devices, so I would need to implement a way, that the key is online marked as used and unused, when the program is getting uninstalled.

Answer (score 2):

I would try asking this on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead of here - but I'd advice you to look into **(non)-commercial products/API's** to help you out (e.g. http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) in stead of reinventing the wheel. As it's not your core business, you'll likely have a less optimal solution (and thus weak and leaky solution) than what others might provide you with.

Some products you can look into:

**free**

- QLicense (on CodeProject): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996001/A-Ready-To-Use-Software-Licensing-Solution-in-Csha

**pay to use**

- SSWare's CryptoLicensing: http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm
- SORACO: https://soraco.co/quick-license-manager/?gclid=CjwKEAiAirXFBRCQyvL279Tnx1ESJAB-G-Qvy65J7uzmMUClDy0fltJKN7U9HtFex5akQ-H3r7YgFhoCa7nw_wcB

---

PS: if you would start implementing a licensing solution on your own, please drop implementing the same algorithm in both the deployed code as well as the generator - it's too easy to reverse engineer. Try to use some mathematical formulas that support public/private key mechanisms for example, or as I said try to rely on a library/api that's specialised in this domain.

Comment: @someone1 might check the QLicense product maybe... As for registering your "keys" online - once a key is issued, i'd say lock it down to a specific user - and build a webservice where the user can register his software? But as I said, be on the lookout on the API links (and google others) to see if they provide a more waterproof solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Since your code can be reverse-engineered, there is not real way to provide safe solution for your key storage. All your variables hard-coded into application, or in separate files, where they are encrypted using the same application are not safe. You need to treat them as **publicly available**.

Second even if you will provide way of server key authentication, again. Your code can be reverse-engineered. Hacker will remove authentication part, and will re-build your application, DRM free.

Third, even if you whole code, will be crypted, there are still ways to decode that and remove authentication (look denuvo latest failures).

If you will connect code crypting and server side key authentication depending on how many people will be involved in hacking you can delay them be finite amount of time.

**Solution:**

There are 100% secure ways to prevent your application to be hackable, you need to make it 100% web based. There are solutions like ASP.Net if you wish to use C# as server engine.

Comment: Very true! If you don't need to go the desktop route, then it's best to make it sort of webbased. Or maybe a thin client that still needs to connect to the server to get results and data and calculations which you have on the server - and thus your business logic isn't distributed on every machine.